# Javascript not running when echo from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to print some code from PHP after clicking button in JavaScript, however the code is not running and I can't see any errors.

```php
<script type="text/javascript  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
3.4.1.min.js" > 
$( document ).ready(function() {
<?php echo '$("button[data-id='. $transport[0]['request']['vehicleType'] 
. ']" ).click();'; ?>
});
</script>

...

<script type="text/JavaScript  src=" https:="" code.jquery.com="" jquery 
3.4.1.min.js"=""> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("button[data-id=seated]" ).click();});
</script>
```

Running the code in console works just fine and the button is clicked,however echoing from php the code is present without errors but not executed and the button is not clicked.

Comment: This looks ok to you? `<script type="text/JavaScript  src=" https:="" code.jquery.com="" jquery 
3.4.1.min.js"="">`

Comment: First problem is that you can't combine `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
3.4.1.min.js` and code in the same `script` tag

Comment: Firstly welcome to our community :) 
Secondly as @CarstenLøvboAndersen said you cant combine. After that type = "text/javascript " you must close the " this

Comment: @İsaGİRİŞKEN need some backticks in there for code `

Comment: Just look at your syntax, it is really a mess. Start with that and edit your code afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" >  </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

 $( document ).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ <?php echo '$("button[data-id='. $transport[0]['request']['vehicleType'] . ']" )[0].click()' ?> }, 100)
  setTimeout(function(){  <?php echo '$("input[value='.  $transport[0]['request']['vehicleSpecification'] . ']")[0].click();'; ?> }, 100)
});
 </script>
```

A small time out and ref to element 0  was enough to make it work

Answer (score 0):

the code is not working even like this

php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" >  </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  <?php echo '$("button[data-id='. $transport[0]['request']['vehicleType'] . ']" ).click();'; ?>
});
 </script>
```

js output

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("button[data-id=seated]" ).click();});
 </script>
```

those missing quotes and slashes came from formatting my question, im new to the forum so i wasn't sure how to format the code.

Comment: All that's going to do is call the "click" event on a button, so if there's something like this in your code: `<button data-id="seated" onclick="alert('Hello?');">Clicky</button>` it'll pop up an alert box saying "Hello?" ... that's all.

Comment: Yes but the click event doesn't fire and the button is not clicked and i don't see any errors also putting an alert in the code makes it obvious it is not working.

Comment: Does your button have the `data-id` of "seated"? My example is working on JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z5y96a7f/

Comment: Yes and the code is working when i run it in the console  my button is clicked but it is not fired when i echo it from my php. i have 3 buttons who i  call dynamically where one of them has the data-id seated. the problem is that it is not clicked when i load my page while i can't see why.